# How to load devexpress report designer in preview mode in Angular

Tags: angular, devexpress

I want to load the `dx-report-designer` in preview mode. I have found a solution  for ASP.Net MVC:

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T467401/start-report-designer-with-preview-mode-in-mvc

But can't find anything for Angular. Any suggestion?

Comment: Why did you down-vote the question? You should inform the reason in the comment when down-voting a question, so that the questioner can learn and improve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I could load it in preview mode with the following code in the CustomizeMenuActions:

```
          setTimeout(() => {
      event.sender.ShowPreview();
  }, 1);
```